# PHP Random images with links - how to add text/title?

Tags: php, html, image, random, hyperlink

```
<?php
// Random Image With Link
// https://getbutterfly.com/
//
// Usage:
//
// Save this file as ads.php and use the include function to call it inside your web site

function display_random_img($array) {
    $key = rand(0 , count($array) -1);
    $link_url = $array[$key]['url'];
    $alt_tag = $array[$key]['alt'];
    $random_img_url = $array[$key]['img_url'];
    list($img_width, $img_height) = getimagesize($random_img_url);
    return "<a href=\"$link_url\"><img src=\"$random_img_url\" width=\"$img_width\" height=\"$img_height\" alt=\"$alt_tag\" /></a>";
}

// Edit the following values accordingly
$ads_array = array(
    array(
        'url' => 'http://www.google.com/',
        'alt' => 'Google',
        'img_url' => 'images/1.png'
    ),
    array(
        'url' => 'http://www.yahoo.com/',
        'alt' => 'Yahoo!',
        'img_url' => 'images/2.png'
    ),
    array(
        'url' => 'http://www.msn.com/',
        'alt' => 'MSN',
        'img_url' => 'images/3.png'
    )
);
$ads_array_1 = array( // add or remove accordingly
    array(
        'url' => 'http://www.google.com/',
        'alt' => 'Google',
        'img_url' => 'images/1.png'
    ),
    array(
        'url' => 'http://www.yahoo.com/',
        'alt' => 'Yahoo!',
        'img_url' => 'images/2.png'
    ),
    array(
        'url' => 'http://www.msn.com/',
        'alt' => 'MSN',
        'img_url' => 'images/3.png'
    )
);

echo display_random_img($ads_array);
echo display_random_img($ads_array_1); // add or remove accordingly
?>
```

While searching on the internet for a viable PHP array randomizer function, this is what I ended up with. It works perfectly, there are url, alt, img_url. 
I don't know how to **show text** over/with the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

1) Add title to the array :

```
array(
    'url' => 'http://www.google.com/',
    'alt' => 'Google',
    'img_url' => 'images/1.png',
    'title' => 'Google Title'
),
```

2) Replace your function with

```
function display_random_img($array) {
    $key = rand(0 , count($array) -1);
    $link_url = $array[$key]['url'];
    $alt_tag = $array[$key]['alt'];
    $random_img_url = $array[$key]['img_url'];
    $title = $array[$key]['title'];
    list($img_width, $img_height) = getimagesize($random_img_url);
    return "<a href=\"$link_url\"><img src=\"$random_img_url\" width=\"$img_width\" height=\"$img_height\" alt=\"$alt_tag\" title=\"$title\" /></a>";
}
```

If You want Your title to be next to the image or whatever, just make the relevant corrections in html :

```
return "$title : <a href=\"$link_url\"><img src=\"$random_img_url\" width=\"$img_width\" height=\"$img_height\" alt=\"$alt_tag\" title=\"$title\" /></a>";
```

Comment: Thank you! 

i'll try something like this:

 return "<h1 style=\"...\">$title</h1><a href=\"$link_url\"><img src=\"$random_img_url\" width=\"$img_width\" height=\"$img_height\" alt=\"$alt_tag\" title=\"$title\" /></a>";

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean hover text... set the title of your image tag to the text you want displayed

eg:

```
<img title="some hover text" ...
```

In order to pull this off smoothly you would just need to add a 'title' element to each item in the array.

If that first assumption is wrong and what you want to do is display some text along with the image do something like:

```
<a href=...>
    <img .../>
    some text or html
</a>
```

You can put anything you want inside an anchor tag.